# Solution for comments for a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm introducing comments into a Rails application, and, being exceptionally lazy, I'm looking for a plugin to do it for me. I came across [acts-as-commentable](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/18/acts-as-commentable-plugin/), but I didn't find much else. Acts-as-commentable seems fine, but it doesn't have support for threading.

Of course, it wouldn't be too hard just to home-brew the entire thing, but I think that surely commenting is such a common feature that there should be a canonical plugin to handle it. Can somebody with perhaps more Google Fu than me point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is acts_as_commentable_with_threading plugin which help you for threaded comment.
Link::
http://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading

Answer (score 0):

The most lazy approach would be to use third-party commenting system like [DISQUS](http://disqus.com/) : just copypaste a couple of javascripts and you're done.

Surely, it can't be used if your app has an authentication system of its own.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to integrate a third-party service like Disqus, you have [Juvia](https://github.com/phusion/juvia) [The Comments](https://github.com/the-teacher/the_comments) and [Commontator](https://github.com/lml/commontator). Also you can count with [opinio](https://github.com/Draiken/opinio) as alternative. but only with Rails 3 and at the moment and as notice the development seems stalled.